# Can't get element value by css or xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

i tried to get the value of an element by xpath and css, and tried with .text and .get_attribute('value'), but no way to get it.

element:

```
<div class="itemWrapper-tp4JSoHa"> [flex]
  <div class="value-tp4JSoHa">1205.61</div
```

code 1:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='value-tp4JSoHa']")))
equity = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='value-tp4JSoHa']")
num_equity = equity.text #int(equity.text) 
return num_equity
```

RESULT = 0

code 2:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='value-tp4JSoHa']")))
equity = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.itemWrapper-tp4JSoHa:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1)').get_attribute('value') 
return equity
```

RESULT = NONE

Any solutions?

Comment: url of the site?

Comment: Tradingview chart, inside of the trading panel and then logged into broker. I'm trying to get the broker account equity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to your code 1 example:

- Do the "clever" trick of replacing `find_element_by_xpath` with `find_elements_by_xpath` (a minor difference) that *now* returns a list of results
- Now either iterate over the list, or select the first element with the index `[0]`:

  ```
  num_equity = equity[0].text #int(equity.text)
  ```

  which gives you `1205.61`
- And if you want to return the count of elements in the list, use

  ```
  num_equity = len(equity)
  ```

Comment: or use an XPath expression which is guaranteed to return at most 1 item, e.g. (//*[@class='value-tp4JSoHa'])[1]